LSTM and GRU Models Not Properly Predicting Future Dates for stic=
I am building a prediction model using GRU and LSTM models as shown below. The user is instructed to enter how many days into the future they would like to predict, majority of test have been 30 days. However when the graph is displayed, it appears to be taking the last 90ish days of data and making predictions identical to those data points instead of 30 days of predictions like requested by the user. I'm wondering if my scaling is off or if there is something else I am missing.
enter image description here
def prepare_lstm_data(data):
    df = data[['y']]

    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(df)

    train_data_len = int(np.ceil(len(scaled_data) * 0.8))

    train_data = scaled_data[0:train_data_len, :]

    X_train, y_train = [], []
    for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
        X_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0])
        y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])

    X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))

    return X_train, y_train, scaler, scaled_data, train_data_len

# Function to build and train the LSTM model
def build_lstm_model(X_train, y_train):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(25))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=10)
    
    return model

# Function to run LSTM prediction model
def run_lstm(data, prediction_length):
    X_train, y_train, scaler, scaled_data, train_data_len = prepare_lstm_data(data)

    lstm_model = build_lstm_model(X_train, y_train)

    test_data = scaled_data[train_data_len - 60:, :]
    X_test = []
    for i in range(60, len(test_data)):
        X_test.append(test_data[i-60:i, 0])

    X_test = np.array(X_test)
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

    predictions = lstm_model.predict(X_test)
    predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)

    future_dates = pd.date_range(start=data['ds'].iloc[-1], periods=len(predictions) + 1, freq='D')[1:]
    forecast_df = pd.DataFrame({'ds': future_dates, 'yhat': predictions.flatten()})

    return forecast_df

#Function to prepare the data for the GRU model
def prepare_gru_data(data):
    df = data[['y']]

    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(df)

    train_data_len = int(np.ceil(len(scaled_data) * 0.8))

    train_data = scaled_data[0:train_data_len, :]

    X_train, y_train = [], []
    for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
        X_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0])
        y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])

    X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))

    return X_train, y_train, scaler, scaled_data, train_data_len

#Function to build and train GRU Model
def build_gru_model(X_train, y_train):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(GRU(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
    model.add(GRU(50, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(25))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=10)
    
    return model
    
#Function to run GRU prediciton model
def run_gru(data, prediction_length):
    X_train, y_train, scaler, scaled_data, train_data_len = prepare_gru_data(data)

    gru_model = build_gru_model(X_train, y_train)

    test_data = scaled_data[train_data_len - 60:, :]
    X_test = []
    for i in range(60, len(test_data)):
        X_test.append(test_data[i-60:i, 0])

    X_test = np.array(X_test)
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

    predictions = gru_model.predict(X_test)
    predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)

    future_dates = pd.date_range(start=data['ds'].iloc[-1], periods=len(predictions) + 1, freq='D')[1:]
    forecast_df = pd.DataFrame({'ds': future_dates, 'yhat': predictions.flatten()})

    return forecast_df


I have tried altering the ranges like indicated in the lines "for i in range(60, len(train_data)):"
but that sees to just return errors.
